# Can we make [climate-change] a synonym for [global-warming]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Can we make [climate-change](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate-change) a synonym for [global-warming](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/global-warming)?

Although these terms have different meanings within the scientific community, and especially among climate researchers, they are often used interchangeably in the common vernacular. When considered in the context of vegetarianism, they are basically identical.

Furthermore, climate change seems to be [slightly more popular](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=climate%20change,global%20warming) in North America. I personally have almost tagged questions with climate-change before realizing there was already a global-warming tag.

There are no questions currently carrying the [climate-change](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate-change) tag, so this would only affect newly asked questions going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question to clearly state that no action is needed.

I never should have asked this question, because it doesn't make sense to tag action on tags that don't have any questions attached.